# Copiar última fila y pegar en la última fila disponible

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito de su ayuda en google apps script. Necesito generar un código donde de una hoja obtener la ultima fila, copiar esa fila(obtener), y posteriormente pegar en otra hoja en la ultima fila disponible. He intentado varios métodos y visto tutoriales, pero no logro dar con la solución.

De antemano agradezco la ayuda...

```
function copiar () {
  
    var ultimoregistro = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OFcSSL0-KgyBrlHTC9R6fTKR94XoxYfL8OPDalUlM30").getSheetByName("Hoja 1").getRange("A1:A").getValues().filter(String).length;

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Hoja 3");
    var ultfila = ss.getLastRow();

    SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OFcSSL0-KgyBrlHTC9R6fTKR94XoxYfL8OPDalUlM30").getSheetByName("Hoja 1").getRange(1 + ultimoregistro,1,1,3).setValues(ultfila);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [so.es]. Por favor describe que es lo que hace tu código y si este devuelve un mensaje de error indica textualmente cuál es. También indica si estás familiarizado con JavaScript y tu duda es especifica sobre el servicio de hoja de cálculo de Google Apps Script (SpreadsheetApp) o de programación en general. P.S. No te recomiendo usar cadenas tan largas como la de `ultimoregistro` porque eso hace difícil depurar el código especialmente si no estas familiarizado con el editor de Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

Este Funcion te puede servir, para copiar la ultima fila de la "Hoja 1" a otra hoja

```
function copiarUltimaFila() {

   var idSS = "1m3-ce76Vmw4ZRZoOgjBnJL6Z-eryG9sU51nYOtzZayY";
   var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById( idSS );

   var hoja1      = SS.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
   var hojacopiar = SS.getSheetByName("HojaCopiar");                                   

   var DataRangeH1   = hoja1.getDataRange();
   var DatosH1 = DataRangeH1.getValues();
   var UltFila = DataRangeH1.getLastRow()-1;

  console.log ("ultima Fila " + UltFila);
  console.log ("datos ultima fila " + DatosH1[UltFila]);

  hojacopiar.appendRow(DatosH1[UltFila]); // con appendRow() agrega la final de la hoja "HojaCopiar" el contenido del Array

}
```